# Upload, edit, delete multiple files using Symfony form embed collections

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to upload multiple files see code below:

### File Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Files
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="files")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FilesRepository")
 */
class Files
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="file", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the product brochure as a PDF file.")
     * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "application/pdf" })
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     *
     * @return Files
     */
    function getUser() {
        return $this->user();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set file
     *
     * @param string $file
     *
     * @return Files
     */
    public function setFile($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get file
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }
}
```

### User entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User{

        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $name;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="lastName", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $lastName;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Files", cascade={"persist"})
         */
        private $files;

        function __construct() {
            $this->files = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return int
         */
        public function getId() {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set name
         *
         * @param string $name
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setName($name) {
            $this->name = $name;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get name
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getName() {
            return $this->name;
        }

        /**
         * Set lastName
         *
         * @param string $lastName
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setLastName($lastName) {
            $this->lastName = $lastName;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get lastName
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getLastName() {
            return $this->lastName;
        }

        /**
         * Get files
         *
         * @return ArrayCollection
         */
        function getFiles() {
            return $this->files;
        }

        /**
         * Set files
         * @param type $files
         */
        function setFiles($files) {
            $this->files = $files;
        }
    }
```

### UserType:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use AppBundle\Form\FilesType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('lastName')
            ->add('files', CollectionType::class,array(
                'entry_type' => FilesType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_user';
    }
}
```

### FilesType:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FilesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('file');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Files'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_files';
    }
}
```

### Files Controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Files;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * File controller.
 *
 * @Route("files")
 */
class FilesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all file entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="files_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $files = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Files')->findAll();

        return $this->render('files/index.html.twig', array(
            'files' => $files,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new file entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="files_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $file = new File();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\FilesType', $file);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($file);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('files_show', array('id' => $file->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('files/new.html.twig', array(
            'file' => $file,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a file entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="files_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showAction(Files $file)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($file);

        return $this->render('files/show.html.twig', array(
            'file' => $file,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing file entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="files_edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Files $file)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($file);
        $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\FilesType', $file);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('files_edit', array('id' => $file->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('files/edit.html.twig', array(
            'file' => $file,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a file entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="files_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, Files $file)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($file);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($file);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('files_index');
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a file entity.
     *
     * @param Files $file The file entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm(Files $file)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('files_delete', array('id' => $file->getId())))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->getForm()
            ;
    }
}
```

### UserController:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * User controller.
 *
 * @Route("user")
 */
class UserController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Lists all user entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="user_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $users = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findAll();

        return $this->render('user/index.html.twig', array(
            'users' => $users,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new user entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="user_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request) {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UserType', $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $attachments = $user->getFiles();

            if ($attachments) {
                foreach($attachments as $attachment)
                {
                    $file = $attachment->getFile();

                    var_dump($attachment);
                    $filename = md5(uniqid()) . '.' .$file->guessExtension();

                    $file->move(
                        $this->getParameter('upload_path'), $filename
                    );
                    var_dump($filename);
                    $attachment->setFile($filename);
                }
            }

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_show', array('id' => $user->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('user/new.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a user entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="user_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showAction(User $user) {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($user);

        return $this->render('user/show.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing user entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="user_edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, User $user) {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($user);
        $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UserType', $user);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_edit', array('id' => $user->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('user/edit.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a user entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="user_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, User $user) {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($user);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_index');
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a user entity.
     *
     * @param User $user The user entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm(User $user) {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('user_delete', array('id' => $user->getId())))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->getForm()
            ;
    }
}
```

### Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>File</h1>

    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <td>{{ file.id }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>File</th>
            <td>{{ file.file }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('files_index') }}">Back to the list</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('files_edit', { 'id': file.id }) }}">Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            {{ form_start(delete_form) }}
            <input type="submit" value="Delete">
            {{ form_end(delete_form) }}
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

I am having two problems. I can upload one file and multiple files, but when I try to show file for example an image, it does not show the image. Instead it just shows the path or name like this: **576e628f70c22f3264249e60bd0c9700.docx**
or **003a916b73e8f5ab3811fa88183ad951.pdf**.

The second problem is when trying to edit, it gives me the following error:

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, but is a(n) string. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File. I tried to set data_class optin to null but it gave another error it didn't work.

Can someone help me fix these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you are doing, when you upload new files, you put them in a specific location ( with  $file->move(...); ) then store only the names of those files in your User entity ( with $attachment->setFile($filename); )

so when you try to edit the ser entity, the FormType expects an array of File but instead gets an array of String because that's what you got stored in the database and that's what Symfony gets from the database and puts into your entity.

**Solution** : in the editAction, create new file objects with the path to each file and put those objects in place of the names of files, that way symfony gets the File he expects and won't give you an error.

When you submit the edit form, don't forget to convert the files back to the String format so they can be stored in the database

**EDIT :**

As for the first problem, like i said, you are storing the names of your files in the entity, so when show them with {{ file.file }} , it will show you the name of the file because that's it's content, every file type has a proper way of showing it. Example : if your file is an image, you do like this : < img src="{{ file.file }}" / > , of course you have to include the complete path to that image starting from the web folder

As for the .pdf, .docx and other file types, you just have to figure out a way to show their contents as you need

Comment: thanx I will try that and I will let you know if it workes, but do you have maybe a solution for the first problem to?

Comment: Can you give an example with what I can Change  ( with $attachment->setFile($filename); ) in order to add the path to db instead of the name. I am new to this I followed symfony documentation and they do it like that. I know your answer is correct.

Comment: if it's correct then mark it as correct, a vote up would be nice too, the path is the value of the parameter 'upload_path' plus the file name, you did very good putting it in a parameter instead of directly in the file names, you just have to add the value of that parameter to the file name when you want to show them ( you used the parameter in your controller with $this->getParameter('upload_path'); you just have to do it with twig )

Comment: Can you look here my edited error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45927047/symfony-update-and-delete-multiple-files-using-doctrine