# Symfony Update and delete multiple files using doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to Update (multiple) uploaded  files

I am having two problems. When I try to enter the edit form from index.html twig it gives me the following error:

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, but is a(n) string. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File.

I tried to set data_class option to null but it gave another error it didn't work.

So not when I try to update but when I try to go to the edit form. I have tried multiple solution from other questions on stack overflow but I keep getting this error.

Second problem is at the moment when I try to delete file, it only delete from database not the file. I know I haven't Referred to the location of the file when I delete. I don't know how to do that. I have seen some examples of Symfony 2 but it didn't work when I tried. Can someone help me fix these problems?

**Edit**

I have set FileType  `$builder->add('file',FileType::class, array( 'data_class' => null, 'by_reference' => false,));` after clearing cash multiple time I can finaly enter the page but nou it does not show the uploaded file, but it does show name and lastname. If I add this `<a href="{{ asset('upload/' ~ element.file) }}">view</a>` to my form then it gives me error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Symfony\Component\Form\FormView could not be converted to string").

So if I try update by adding new file It gives me error `file location does not exist` That is probably A problem with my twig How Can I return the uploaded file because I do use user.id to show the uploaded data.

### File Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Tests\StringableObject;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
//use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * Files
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="files")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FilesRepository")
 */
class Files
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="file", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the product brochure as a PDF file.")
     * @Assert\File( maxSize = "100M")
     *
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $path;


    public function addUser(User $user)
    {
        if (!$this->user->contains($user)) {
            $this->user->add($user);
        }
    }
    /**
     * @param $path
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }


//
//    /**
//     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", cascade={"persist"})
//     */
//    private $user;
//
//    function __construct() {
//        $this->user = new ArrayCollection();
//    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Files
     */
    function getUser() {
        return $this->user();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set file
     *
     * @param string $file
     *
     * @return Files
     */
    public function setFile($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get file
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }
    /**
     * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (! in_array($this->file->getMimeType(), array(
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/gif',
            'image/png',
            'video/mp4',
            'video/quicktime',
            'video/avi',
        ))) {
            $context
                ->buildViolation('Wrong file type (jpg,gif,png,mp4,mov,avi)')
                ->atPath('fileName')
                ->addViolation()
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

### User entity:

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Tests\StringableObject;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
//use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * Files
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="files")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FilesRepository")
 */
class Files
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="file", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the product brochure as a PDF file.")
     * @Assert\File( maxSize = "100M")
     *
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $path;


    public function addUser(User $user)
    {
        if (!$this->user->contains($user)) {
            $this->user->add($user);
        }
    }
    /**
     * @param $path
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }


//
//    /**
//     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", cascade={"persist"})
//     */
//    private $user;
//
//    function __construct() {
//        $this->user = new ArrayCollection();
//    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Files
     */
    function getUser() {
        return $this->user();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set file
     *
     * @param string $file
     *
     * @return Files
     */
    public function setFile($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get file
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }
    /**
     * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (! in_array($this->file->getMimeType(), array(
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/gif',
            'image/png',
            'video/mp4',
            'video/quicktime',
            'video/avi',
        ))) {
            $context
                ->buildViolation('Wrong file type (jpg,gif,png,mp4,mov,avi)')
                ->atPath('fileName')
                ->addViolation()
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

### UserType:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use AppBundle\Form\FilesType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('lastName')
        ->add('files', CollectionType::class,array(
            'entry_type' => FilesType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete'=> true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ))
    ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_user';
    }
}
```

### FilesType:

```
    namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;

class FilesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('file',FileType::class, array(
        // ...
        'data_class' => null,
        'by_reference' => false,
    ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Files'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_files';
    }


}
```

### UserController:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Lists all user entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="user_index")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $users = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findAll();

    return $this->render('user/index.html.twig', array(
        'users' => $users,
    ));
}

/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 *   Creates a new user entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="user_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UserType', $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $attachments = $user->getFiles();

        if ($attachments) {

            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                $file = $attachment->getFile();

                // var_dump($attachment);
                $filename = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

                $file->move(
                    $this->getParameter('upload_path'), $filename
                );
                // var_dump($filename);
                $attachment->setFile($filename);
            }
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_show', array('id' => $user->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('user/new.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
 * Finds and displays a user entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="user_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function showAction(User $user)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($user);

    return $this->render('user/show.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing user entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="user_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($user);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UserType', $user);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $attachments = $user->getFiles();

        if ($attachments) {

            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                $file = $attachment->getFile();

                // var_dump($attachment);
                $filename = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

                $file->move(
                    $this->getParameter('upload_path'), $filename
                );

                // var_dump($filename);
                $attachment->setFile(
                    new File($this->getParameter('upload_path') . '/' . $attachment->getFile())
                );
            }
        }

        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_edit', array('id' => $user->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('user/new.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
 * Deletes a user entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="user_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($user);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('user_index');
}

/**
 * Creates a form to delete a user entity.
 *
 * @param User $user The user entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createDeleteForm(User $user)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('user_delete', array('id' => $user->getId())))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->getForm();
}
```

}

### Template:

```
**Index.html.twig**
  <tbody>
                    {% for user in users %}
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="{{ path('user_show', { 'id': user.id }) }}">{{ user.id }}</a></td>
                            <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                                    <li>
                                        <a type="button" class="btn btn-info"
                                           href="{{ path('user_show', { 'id': user.id }) }}">show</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs"
                                           href="{{ path('user_edit', { 'id': user.id }) }}">edit</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>

**Edit.twig.html**

     <div class="row-fluid">
            {{ form_start(form) }}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_row(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_row(form.lastName, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
            <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="files" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.files.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
                {% for element in form.files %}
                    <li>
                        {{ form_widget(element.file) }}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            <input  class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Create"/>
            {{ form_end(form) }}

            <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                <li>
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="{{ path('user_index') }}">Back to
                        the list</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: for the first problem, you should add enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form

Comment: It stil does not help I can upload multiple files but update is not working

Comment: I mean when I try to g to the edit form it directly gives me error.

Comment: @hous Can you please look at my edited Question?

Comment: @paris93 another error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ You must change your form FilesType:

$builder->add('file', FileType::class); (make sure you import FileType class)
and don't forget to use AddFile, removeFile methodes under your entity with by_reference to false to make it add/delete file 
take a look at [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html).

2/Note that you can use the [remove](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html#remove) function of the filesystem component. If you don't want to use the filesystem component, that's fine, you can use unlink(), there is a great example in this remove function of the doc:
public function removeUpload()

```
{
    if (isset($this->file)) {
        unlink($this->file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you look at my entity and Filtype please. I have edited but it still keep giving me same error while trying to enter edit page. I cannot eve enter the page. could this be because of my edit twig?

Comment: Can you please look my edited question? @T. Abdelmalek

Comment: look at doc [link]https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html[link] and use the same to have your uploaded file.

Comment: I am using the same but with form embded collection. Uploading file is working fine but I am having trouble with updating files. When select an uploaded file and I go to the update page, my edit form does return name and lastname values but not file. It shows 0 file selected and I cant see any thing about that in symfony docs

Comment: create a new object file with the existing path and name (stored in DB when created it first time) when displayed your template to update.

Comment: thanx I will try

Comment: I have posted your name in my anther question I will appreciate If you can help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978170/symfony-calculate-number-of-days-based-on-date). And how can I mark your answer as right answer here

Comment: i don't know how but you can search or view some guide in your profile.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you help my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978170/symfony-calculate-number-of-days-based-on-date) Please I am really stuck. I can get a job If I make this.